# ViewPager2 onpageselected called multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I am implementing Viewpager2 in my app. I have to slide my views when **onPageSelected** called. But I observed in log that **onPageSeletd** is being called multiple times.

```
 private void setViewPagerPreviews() {
    onPageChangeCallback = new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);               
            Log.e(TAG, "onPageSelected" + position);
           
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    };
    mEndLessViewpager.registerForPageChangeCallback(onPageChangeCallback);
}
```

Please provide any solution that it can be called only once.

Comment: "I have to slide my views when onPageSelected called" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: To get the viewholder from adapter and alter the view positions based on selected position.

Comment: You should use a `TabLayoutMediator` to handle swipe communication between `ViewPager2` & `TabLayout`

Comment: "To get the viewholder from adapter and alter the view positions based on selected position" -- make sure that you are not changing the pager itself as you do this. And, make sure that you have not registered multiple listeners.

Comment: @CommonsWare Greetings! , Thank you for suggestion, I have checked in my code. I am not altering any view pager, if i remove sliding functionality, still onPageSelected called multiple times, and i am registering only once.